# SQL Query to ignore adjacent matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an activity table that contains various activities and a hash of `(actorEntity|subjectEntity|activity-type)`

There may be cases where a user performs the exact same activity twice in a matter of seconds, meaning there would be two adjacent rows in the database with exactly the same data.

For some use cases, we do not want to display duplicate activities so we filter out duplicates in the application right now based on the hash.  The only problem is that these activities are also paged in some cases, meaning that pulling out records from the result set in the application screws with the paging.

I am searching for a way to do this in SQL so that paging can be done at the DB level.

Given data:

```
id  | message           | from  | hash
-------------------------------------
1   | hello             | bryan | b-hello
2   | goodbye           | bryan | b-goodbye
3   | goodbye           | john  | j-goodbye
4   | goodbye           | john  | j-goodbye 
5   | hello             | john  | j-hello   
6   | goodbye           | john  | j-goodbye
```

I'd like to retreive the following result set:

```
id  | message           | from  | hash
-------------------------------------
1   | hello             | bryan | b-hello
2   | goodbye           | bryan | b-goodbye
4   | goodbye           | john  | j-goodbye
5   | hello             | john  | j-hello
6   | goodbye           | john  | j-goodbye
```

Notice that while rows 3 and 4 are identical, only one is in the desired result set because they were adjacent.  Even though row 6 was the same hash, it should be included in the results since it was not adjacent to another identical hash.

I do not care which of the adjacent rows are returned in the results since they are the same.

I am using MySql 5.5.

Comment: +1 Nice question! But can you show us what have you tried?

Comment: you can try `group by` but you'll need a `date` column which should be rounded per "meaningful time difference" between actions

Comment: Have you thought about adding a flag field indicating whether the record should be printed or not?

Comment: Can the user only perform the action twice or is it possible for 3 or more adjacent rows to be the same?

Comment: There is no limit on how many times the action can be performed, so its possible there could be 3 or more identical adjacent rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out: * [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce86b/1) I am a little doubtful as if this was too simple for what you asked. So please comment. I added more duplicate records to sample data. The following query is removing the latest duplicates, keeping the first entry.

Sample data:

```
ID  MESSAGE     FROMA   HASHA
1   hello       bryan   b-hello
2   goodbye     bryan   b-goodbye
3   goodbye     john    j-goodbye
4   goodbye     john    j-goodbye
5   goodbye     john    j-goodbye
6   hello       john    j-hello
7   goodbye     bryan   b-goodbye
8   goodbye     bryan   b-goodbye
```

Query to find identical record (the latest one or more):

```
select* from actors a
join actors b
where b.id + 1 = a.id
and b.hasha = a.hasha
;
```

Result:

```
ID  MESSAGE     FROMA   HASHA
4   goodbye     john    j-goodbye
5   goodbye     john    j-goodbye
8   goodbye     bryan   b-goodbye
```

Query to get unique records:

```
select * from actors a
where a.id not in (
select a.id from actors a
join actors b
where b.id + 1 = a.id
and b.hasha = a.hasha
);
```

Results:

```
ID  MESSAGE     FROMA   HASHA
1   hello       bryan   b-hello
2   goodbye     bryan   b-goodbye
3   goodbye     john    j-goodbye
6   hello       john    j-hello
7   goodbye     bryan   b-goodbye
```

Comment: @Bryan Migliorisi Do you have a particulare time frame/interval that you do not want to have duplicates? If that's the case, then this query gets pretty interesting - let us know. We can update you along the same lines.:)

Comment: Well I hadn't thought about time based queries.  That could be interesting also but the requirement for right now was merely adjacent identical rows.

Comment: Just looked through the SqlFiddle and your example definitely appears to give me the results I expected.  Since my Ids are not sequential, I modified it a bit to compare with `b.id > a.id` and my quick test against my actual data set seems to give me what I want. Thanks very much!

Comment: @BryanMigliorisi please mark it if this answer provides you the solution. However, I believe if you have a large recordset, then `IN` is not the most performance supportive operator ;) instead you may do a `inner join`

Comment: @BryanMigliorisi I am glad you worked it out. Care to append the SQLFIDDLE reference you tried out to your question as a reference for the benefit of everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

There are complex ways to solve this problem using MySQL queries, 
but I think the EASIEST solution is to just fix up your paging logic.

I believe you are implementing the paging through something like

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 0,4;  #page1
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 5,9;  #page2
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id LIMIT 10,14;  #page3
```

You are going to have A LOT of trouble if you're going to dealing with duplicate rows like this.
What you ultimately want to do is:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id; #page1 returns id:1~5
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 5 ORDER BY id; #page2 returns id:6~10
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > 10 ORDER BY id; #page3 returns id:11~15
```

**This way you won't have to worry about solving the duplicate row problem through MySQL.
It's much simpler.**

Comment: How do you decide which `id` to put in `where clause`?

Comment: The last `id` in your previous page will be the `id` for your next query. In my example, as you can see, the first page got ids 1~5. The last `id` was 5, so the next query would have `WHERE id > 5`.