# In SQL, remove adjacent duplicate rows and perform time calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I need to remove adjacent duplicate rows in the `Flow` column below, and just keep the first ones (marked `*` to illustrate). After that, I need to take the time difference between the `1`s and `0`s for all rows and get the total cumulative time.

```
Record Number    Downhole Time      Flow
-------------------------------------------
0        03/27/2013 19:23:48.582    1       *
58       03/27/2013 19:28:12.606    1   
137      03/27/2013 19:32:16.070    0       *
143      03/27/2013 19:33:59.070    0   
255      03/27/2013 19:40:14.070    0   
272      03/29/2013 14:43:55.071    1       *
289      03/29/2013 14:45:44.070    1   
293      03/29/2013 14:45:59.071    0       *
294      03/29/2013 14:46:10.070    0
```

Result with the adjacent records removed:

```
Record Number    Downhole Time      Flow
-------------------------------------------
0        03/27/2013 19:23:48.582    1       *
137      03/27/2013 19:32:16.070    0       *
272      03/29/2013 14:43:55.071    1       *
293      03/29/2013 14:45:59.071    0       *
```

***Final desired result***

```
cumulative time difference = 
  (03/27/2013 19:32:16.070 - 03/27/2013 19:23:48.582) 
+ (03/29/2013 14:45:59.071 - 03/29/2013 14:43:55.071) 
+ if there are more rows.
```

Comment: Which database is this for (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: What does "first one" mean, lowest `Unique` or earliest `Time`?
-- What do you exactly mean by time difference for all rows, each consecutive pair? Can you give an example?

Comment: @DanielSparing I have edited and added example steps.

Comment: I got you started on formatting your query. Please finish it up so others can read it!

Comment: Please remove your solution (answer) from the question and post as an answer below. Also you can accept it (using the green tick to the left). Thanks!

Comment: Note that your intermediate result (not "indeterminate") doesn't match the sample data you provided--it's clear some time editing went on that didn't get into both places.

Comment: @abatishchev: FYI: I've moved the answer from the question to the answer that the OP had left. (The answer they left, originally, just pointed back to the question.)

Comment: @Pavan: If you feel that your solution was the best answer to your problem, you should mark it as the answer. (If you remember; I acknowledge that this is a six year old question!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does the job you requested:

```
WITH FlowIntervals AS (
   SELECT
      FromTime = Min(D.[Downhole Time]),
      X.ToTime
   FROM
      dbo.vLog D
      OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT TOP 1 ToTime = D2.[Downhole Time]
         FROM dbo.vLog D2
         WHERE
            D.[Downhole Time] < D2.[Downhole Time]
            AND D.[Flow] <> D2.[Flow]
         ORDER BY D2.[Downhole Time]
      ) X
   WHERE D.Flow = 1
   GROUP BY X.ToTime
)
SELECT Sum(DateDiff(ms, FromTime, IsNull(ToTime, GetDate())) / 1000.0)
FROM FlowIntervals
;
```

This query works in SQL 2005 and up. It will perform decently, but requires a self-join of the vLog table and so it may not perform as well as a solution using `LEAD` or `LAG`.

If you are looking for the absolute best possible performance, this query may do the trick:

```
WITH Ranks AS (
   SELECT
      Grp =
         Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY [Downhole Time])
         - Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Flow ORDER BY [Downhole Time]),
      [Downhole Time],
      Flow
   FROM dbo.vLog
), Ranges AS (
   SELECT
      Result = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Min(R.[Downhole Time]), X.Num) / 2,
      [Downhole Time] = Min(R.[Downhole Time]),
      R.Flow, X.Num
   FROM
      Ranks R
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) X (Num)
   GROUP BY
      R.Flow, R.Grp, X.Num
), FlowStates AS (
   SELECT
      FromTime = Min([Downhole Time]),
      ToTime = CASE WHEN Count(*) = 1 THEN NULL ELSE Max([Downhole Time]) END,
      Flow = IsNull(Min(CASE WHEN Num = 2 THEN Flow ELSE NULL END), Min(Flow))
   FROM Ranges R
   WHERE Result > 0
   GROUP BY Result
)
SELECT
   ElapsedSeconds =
      Sum(DateDiff(ms, FromTime, IsNull(ToTime, GetDate())) / 1000.0)
FROM
   FlowStates
WHERE
   Flow = 1
;
```

Using your sample data, it returns `631.486000` (seconds). If you select just the rows from the `FlowStates` CTE, you get the following result:

```
FromTime                ToTime                  Flow
----------------------- ----------------------- ----
2013-03-27 19:23:48.583 2013-03-27 19:32:16.070 1
2013-03-27 19:32:16.070 2013-03-29 14:43:55.070 0
2013-03-29 14:43:55.070 2013-03-29 14:45:59.070 1
2013-03-29 14:45:59.070 NULL                    0
```

This query works in SQL 2005 and up, and should stack up very well performance-wise against any other solution, including one using `LEAD` or `LAG` (which this simulates in a sneaky way). I'm not promising it will win, but it could do very well and might win after all.

See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614431/how-can-i-detect-and-bound-changes-between-row-values-in-a-sql-table/13618019#13618019) for details on what's going on in the query.

Finally, for a complete solution, here's a Lag/Lead version for SQL Server:

```
WITH StateChanges AS (
   SELECT
      [Downhole Time],
      Flow,
      Lag(Flow) OVER (ORDER BY [Downhole Time]) PrevFlow
   FROM
      dbo.vLog
), Durations AS (
   SELECT
      [Downhole Time], 
      Lead([Downhole Time]) OVER (ORDER BY [Downhole Time]) NextTime,
      Flow
   FROM
      StateChanges
   WHERE
      Flow <> PrevFlow
      OR PrevFlow IS NULL
)
SELECT ElapsedTime = Sum(DateDiff(ms, [Downhole Time], NextTime) / 1000.0)
FROM Durations
WHERE Flow = 1
;
```

This query requires SQL Server 2012 or up. It calculates the state changes (did the flow change?), then selects those where the flow did change, then finally calculates the duration for those where the flow changed from 0 to 1 (the start of a period of Flow).

I'd be interested to see what your actual performance results on I/O and time for this query compared to the others. If you look at just the execution plans, this query will seem to win--but it may not be such a clear winner on actual performance statistics.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you @ErikE. YOur last query took 5s. My posted one took 8s

Comment: Actually the NoDuplicatesFlowTable part of my query is needed. If I take it out, our performance matched. your query got lucky in this dataset (false positives danger)

Comment: Would you please explain the trickier data that my query doesn't handle? Also, how did the other queries perform? What are the indexes on the table? P.S. I also had an inconsistency where by mistake I used `[Record Number]` instead of `[Downhole Time]`--it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of database you are using. Here is a solution with analytical functions and Oracle:

```
SELECT 
  un, 
  mytime, 
  flow,
  lead (mytime) OVER (ORDER BY UN) lead_time,
 (lead (mytime) OVER (ORDER BY UN) - mytime)*24*60 minutes
  FROM (  SELECT un,
                 mytime,
                 flow,
                 LAG (flow) OVER (ORDER BY UN) lag_val
            FROM test
        ORDER BY un) a
 WHERE a.flow != NVL (a.lag_val, 9999)
```

The inner select gets the value of the previous flow with the LAG analytical function. The where clause of the outer select filters the 'duplicate' flows (leaves only the rist occurrence of the change). The outer select also calculates the difference in the times (in minutes) using the LEAD analytical function. This will be great performance wise despite the amount of data you have. 
Let me know what kind of database you are using - there are analytical functions implementation (or workarounds) for most databases... This will work only in Orace.

Comment: I need to replace your From test by From (Select ....). I get the following error for the last order by "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries....unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified". help!

Comment: SELECT 
  [Record Number], 
  [Downhole Time], 
  Flow,
  lead ([Downhole Time]) OVER (ORDER BY [RECORD NUMBER]) lead_time,
 (lead ([Downhole Time]) OVER (ORDER BY [RECORD NUMBER]) - [Downhole Time])*24*60 minutes
  FROM (  SELECT [Record Number],
                 [Downhole Time],
                 Flow,
                 LAG (flow) OVER (ORDER BY [Record Number]) lag_val
            FROM (
  Select [Downhole Time], [Record Number], Value As Flow FROM [newMDF].[dbo].[vLog] where [Event Name] like 'Flow%' AND [Field Name] like 'Flow'
  ) Test_table
        ORDER BY [Record Number]) a
 WHERE ...

Comment: I get the following error in your 6th line, data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator. Removed order by temporarily and Replaced NVL with ISNULL

Comment: Hmm that's weird. I had no idea that SQL Server does not allow order by in an inner select. This might ruin the lag function... Try removing the order by clauses from the inner selects - it will resolve that error. Hopefully SQL Server will apply the order by clause from the analytical function to the actual select as well. Let me see how you can get the time difference between two datetime columns in SQL Server. In Oracle, you just subtract the date values but apparently it's different in SQL Server...

Comment: Instead of the subtract operator, try using datediff. Something like this should give you the time difference between the two in minutes: DateDiff(s, lead ([Downhole Time]) OVER (ORDER BY [RECORD NUMBER], [Downhole Time])%3600/60). Not sure if you'll be able to use the lead function as an argument in datediff though. If not, you'll have to add one more outer select and do the datediff there...

Comment: `ORDER BY` in a derived table or subquery doesn't do anything, so why would the DB engine allow it? The only time `ORDER BY` makes sense in an inner query in SQL Server is when a `TOP` clause is specified--thus giving it meaning that didn't previously exist.

Comment: @Koshera the following got me going but Thank you. I appreciate your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13889565/sql-query-to-ignore-adjacent-matching-rows

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up solving my problem.

```sql
WITH FlowEvntTable AS (
  /* the following gets raw data and adds Row# for the next select to use*/
  SELECT        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Downhole Time]) AS RNum,
                [Downhole Time],
                [Record Number],
                Value AS Flow
  FROM          [newMDF].[dbo].[vLog]
  WHERE         [Event Name] LIKE 'Flow%'
    AND         [Field Name] LIKE 'Flow'
), 
NoDuplicatesFlowTable AS (
  /*the following line came from StackOverflow "ignore adjacent matching rows" */
  SELECT        [Downhole Time],
                [Flow]
  FROM          FlowEvntTable A 
  WHERE         A.RNum NOT IN (
    SELECT        A.RNUM 
    FROM          FlowEvntTable A 
    JOIN          FlowEvntTable B 
       ON         B.RNum +1 = A.RNum 
       AND        B.Flow=A.Flow
  ) 
), 
FlowOffColAddedTable AS (
  SELECT        *, 
                lead([Downhole Time]) 
  OVER          (ORDER BY [Downhole Time]) AS NotFlowTime 
  FROM          NoDuplicatesFlowTable 
), 
FlowStartEndTimeTable AS (
  /*select above adds time offest by 1 row to a new column. now by Flow = 1/On, you get Start End On pairs */
  SELECT        [Downhole Time] AS StartTime,
                NotFlowTime AS EndTime 
  FROM          FlowOffColAddedTable 
  WHERE         Flow = 1
)

/*diff and sum the pairs*/
SELECT          Sum(DATEDIFF(ms,StartTime,EndTime))/1000 AS VibeOnSec 
FROM            FlowStartEndTimeTable
```

**Intermediate result after the `Select *, lead...` above.**

```
Downhole Time         Flow  NotFlowTime  
-------------------------------------------  
2013-03-28 00:23:48.0000000 1   2013-03-28 00:32:16.0000000  
2013-03-28 00:32:16.0000000 0   2013-03-28 00:33:59.0000000  
2013-03-28 00:33:59.0000000 1   2013-03-28 00:40:14.0000000  
2013-03-28 00:40:14.0000000 0   2013-03-29 19:43:55.0000000  
2013-03-29 19:43:55.0000000 1   2013-03-29 19:45:44.0000000
```

> ***Note:*** No, this doesn't match the original data set—it's just meant to give a rough idea of the results.